# AngularJs- Redirect to another view after submitting data to the server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I'm developing a small AngularJs and ASP.net MVC based web application with MongoDb database. And one of it's task is to register yourself if not an already a member. And after successfully submitting data from client side to the server, the user should be redirected to another page.So Data get saved in the database after the submission but It's does not seem to trigger the success function of Angular part where i try to redirect to the other page.

I have attached the image showing non-triggering part of the code highlighting in yellow.

How can i resolve this ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RegisterUser(User user)
    {
        mongoClient = new MongoClient();
        var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase(Database);
        userList = db.GetCollection<User>("user");
        var result = userList.AsQueryable().Where(a => a.UserName.Equals(user.UserName)).SingleOrDefault();
        user.IsActive = true;
        user.UserType = "Visitor";
        string message = "";

        if (result == null)
        {
            var seralizedUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList);
            userList.InsertOne(user);
            //var seralizedUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(userList);
            message = "Success";

            //return Json(seralizedUser, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            return Json(new
            {
                redirectUrl = Url.Action("VisitorChatPanel", "Visitor", ""),
                isRedirect = true
            });

          //  return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
        else
        {
            message = "Failed";
            //var seralizedUser = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(userList);
            var seralizedUser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userList);
         //   return Json(seralizedUser, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                          return Json(new
            {
                redirectUrl = Url.Action("VisitorChatPanel", "Visitor", ""),
                isRedirect = false
            }); 

        }

    }
```

```js
angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('VisitorRegistrationController', function ($scope, RegistrationService) {
    $scope.SubmitText = "Save";
    $scope.IsFormValid = false;
    $scope.Submitted = false;
    $scope.Message = '';
    $scope.User = {
        UserName: '',
        Password: '',
        Email: '',
        FirstName: '',
        LastName: '',
        IsActive: false,
        UserType: 'Visitor'

    };

    //validates form on client side
    $scope.$watch('f1.$valid', function (newValue) {
        $scope.isFormValid = newValue;
    });

    //Save Data
    $scope.SaveData = function (data) {
        if ($scope.SubmitText == 'Save') {
            $scope.Submitted = true;
            $scope.Message = '';

            if ($scope.isFormValid) {
               // $scope.SubmitText = 'Please Wait...';
                $scope.User = data;
                alert('data : ' + $scope.User.FirstName);
                RegistrationService.SaveFormData($scope.User).then(function (d) {
                    alert(d);
                    if (d == 'Success') {
                        //have to clear form here
                        ClearForm();
                    }
                    $scope.SubmitText = "Save";
                });
            }
            else {
                $scope.Message = '';
            }
        }
    }
    //Clear Form 
    function ClearForm() {
        $scope.User = {};
        $scope.f1.$setPristine(); //here f1 is form name
        $scope.Submitted = false;
    }
}).factory('RegistrationService', function ($http, $q) {

   
    var fac = {};
    fac.SaveFormData = function (data) {
        //alert('$http : ' + $http);
        var defer = $q.defer();
        alert('q : ' + $q);
        $http({
            url: '/Visitor/RegisterUser',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {'content-type' : 'application/json'}
        }).success(function (d) {
            // Success callback
            alert('Successfully registered !');
            if (d.isRedirect) {
                window.location.href = d.redirectUrl;
            }
            defer.resolve(d);
        }).error(function (e) {
            //Failed Callback
            alert('Error!');
          //  defer.reject(e);
        });
       
          return defer.promise;
        //return 'Successfull';
    }
    return fac;
});
;
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VisitorRegistrationForm";
}

<style>
    body {
        margin-top: 50px;
    }

    input {
        max-width: 300px;
    }

    .error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>


<h2>Visitor Registration Form</h2>
<div class="panel panel-info" style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:500px;">
    
    <div ng-controller="VisitorRegistrationController" class="panel-body">
        <form novalidate name="f1" ng-submit="SaveData(User)" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text text-info col-md-offset-2">First Name : </label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="User.FirstName" class="form-control col-md-offset-2" name="uFirstName" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required autofocus />
                <span class="error col-md-offset-2" ng-show="(f1.uFirstName.$dirty || Submitted) && f1.uFirstName.$error.required">FirstName required!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text text-info col-md-offset-2">Last Name : </label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="User.LastName" class="form-control col-md-offset-2" name="uLastName" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required autofocus />
                <span class="error col-md-offset-2" ng-show="(f1.uLastName.$dirty || Submitted) && f1.uLastName.$error.required">LastName required!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text text-info col-md-offset-2">Email  : </label>
                <input type="email" ng-model="User.Email" class="form-control col-md-offset-2" name="uEmail" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" />
                <span class="error col-md-offset-2" ng-show="(f1.uEmail.$dirty || Submitted) && f1.uEmail.$error.required">Email required</span>
                <span class="error col-md-offset-2" ng-show="(f1.uEmail.$dirty || Submitted) && f1.uEmail.$error.email">Email  not valid!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text text-info col-md-offset-2">UserName : </label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="User.UserName" class="form-control col-md-offset-2" name="uUserName" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required />
                <span class="error col-md-offset-2" ng-show="(f1.uUserName.$dirty || Submitted) && f1.uUserName.$error.required">UserName required!</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="text text-info col-md-offset-2">Password : </label>
                <input type="password" ng-model="User.Password" class="form-control col-md-offset-2" name="uPassword" ng-class="Submitted?'ng-dirty':''" required />
                <span class="error col-md-offset-2" ng-show="(f1.uPassword.$dirty || Submitted) && f1.uPassword.$error.required">Password required!</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label></label>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-2" value="{{SubmitText}}" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]